# How to enable e-mail notifications?

Tags: support

I'd like to receive e-mail notifications for answers to my questions on askubuntu. I've seen in other questions that there should be a box to tick in the preferences of my account to enable that, but I can't seem to find it.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks for me. What am I missing please?

[image: preferences screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the Notification box (the thing that lights up when you do have things that need tending to) there is a link for email notifications. Looks a bit like this:

[image]

You can tweak that around to get messages within 3 hours.

Comment: Ah there it is indeed, thank you.